# removing small dots in list

Tags: html, css

I have removed small dots in `ul > li` by css style:

```
li{list-style:none;}
```

But there are some small dot in `<li>`tag now. How can I remove them. I have searched a lot and used `li,ul{display:block; list-style:none; list-style-type:none; .....}` too. But nothing worked. Inspecting elements was not helpful. Would you please help me remove these blue small dots?

[image: Image of small dots in my html <code><li></code> tag]

Comment: can you share your code pls?

Comment: Please, provide more information (HTML, jsfiddle and etc)

Comment: @soorapadman :  I have removed all classes. It is the pure code: `<div style="background-color: #fff;">
<ul style="list-style: none !important;">
<li style="list-style: none !important;">این فیلد اجباری است.</li>
<li>
متاسفانه, نام کاربری یا گذرواژه قابل شناسایی نیست.
<a href="/user/password?name=x">آیا شما گذرواژه خود را فراموش کرده‌اید؟</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>`

Comment: It works (Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m), what is your browser? Provide jsfiddle at least.

Answer (score 4):

You are using correct css but you have applied it on `li` tag, It should be on `ul` tag.

Use following css:

```
ul{list-style:none;}
```

Comment: I have used that before. But it Does not worked. Thank You any way...
I have used this too: ul{list-style:none; !important}

Comment: Please share your html and css

Answer (score 2):

You can remove bullets by setting the list-style-type        to none on the CSS for the  element, for example

```
ul
{
list-style-type: none;
}
```

You might also want to add padding:0; margin:0; to   that, if you want to remove indentation as well.

See Listutorial for a great walkthrough of list formatting techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it by making it a link(a tag) and then disable the link if don't want it.Maybe an indirect way would help